# Upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\|f(t) - f(t_{i-1})\|dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lipschitz function satisfying $\int_0^\infty\|f(t)\|dt < \infty$ and $0 = t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dots$ be a divergent sequence satisfying $\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(t_i-t_{i-1})<\infty$.
I am trying to prove or disprove the following:

> there exists $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}\|f(t) - f(t_{i-1})\|dt \le M\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(t_i-t_{i-1})$

but cannot make any progress.
Would you give me any hint for this problem?

Comment: Lipschitz means $\|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\| \leq L\cdot \|t_i - t_{i-1}\|$?  Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: @postmortes For now, that is the only assumption for $f$. I may add more assumptions in order to make the statement true but I want to know if it is true or false beforehand.

Comment: @postmortes By the way, Lipschitz continuity of $f$ with the bounded integration on $[0,\infty)$ implies $f(t) \to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: You can prove this if $\int\|f'(s)\|\, ds <\infty$. The condition $\int\|f(s)\|\, ds <\infty$ is too weak for this.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, I think that your integral $I$ is not ensured to be convergent.

Take $f$ to be piecewise affine, with $f(0)=0$ and for all $n \geq 10$, 
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{n\ln{n}},$$
$$f\left(n \pm \frac{1}{\ln{n}}\right)=0.$$

Take $t_n=n+10$.

Then $$\infty=\sum_n{f(t_{n-1})(t_n-t_{n-1})} \leq \sum_n{\int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n}{\|f-f(t_{n-1})\| +\|f\|}} \leq I + \int_{\mathbb{R}^+}{\|f\|}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your idea seems to work also for $f(n) = 1/n$ and $f(n\pm 1/n) = 0$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: It is simpler indeed.